# How to access object data inside an array and object after json_encode executed?

Tags: php, json

I have a json data from API and i want to insert them to my database table. I have extract `$data` using `json_encode` function, but when i tried to access data inside `$myJson` with some of this code, it gives me an error result.

```
$data = '{"posts":[{"post":{"math_score":"85","history_score":"70"}}]}';
$myJson = json_decode($data);

foreach ($myJson as $mj){
    echo $mj['math_score'];
    // echo $mj->math_score; <= error
    // echo $mj[0]->post->math_score; <= error
    // echo $mj->post->math_score; <= error
}
```

> The error : `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

sorry for my bad grammar, any answer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `json_decode()`

Comment: It give me error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built in php function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Try

```
$json = '{"posts":[{"post":{"math_score":"85","history_score":"70"}}]}';

$json = json_decode($json);

echo $json->posts{0}->post->math_score;
```

By default `json_decode` return object. If you want an array then you need to pass second argument `true` to `json_decode`.

**Try it with Array**

```
$json = '{"posts":[{"post":{"math_score":"85","history_score":"70"}}]}';

$json = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json['posts'] as $mj)
{
    echo $mj['post']['math_score'];
}
```

Comment: It works, Thanks Hassaan